# Messages from [IP address] temporarily deferred due to user complaints

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, dovecot, sendmail

I have spent a solid 2 or 3 weeks following tutorials and going through trial and error trying to set up my own mail server using Postfix and Dovecot on Ubuntu 18.04. I finally have SPF/DKIM/DMARC records set up and outgoing mail from my server ONLY to gmail. Yahoo, hotmail, and private servers are not receiving any mail from my server. I have very little experience with this email server stuff, so any advice is welcome. If you need me to add additional info to this post please let me know.

/var/log/mail.log:

```
May 30 14:41:10 nodename postfix/qmgr[19762]: 188C44005B: from=<root@example.com>, size=355, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 30 14:41:10 nodename postfix/smtp[28596]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c07::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
May 30 14:41:10 nodename postfix/smtp[28596]: Untrusted TLS connection established to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.214.27]:25: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits)
May 30 14:41:11 nodename postfix/smtp[28596]: 188C44005B: to=<user1@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.214.27]:25, delay=0.99, delays=0.02/0.01/0.42/0.55, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1590874871 26si9405031jas.5 - gsmtp)
May 30 14:41:11 nodename postfix/qmgr[19762]: 188C44005B: removed
May 30 14:42:00 nodename postfix/qmgr[19762]: C54274005F: from=<root@example.com>, size=355, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 30 14:42:01 nodename postfix/smtp[28596]: Untrusted TLS connection established to mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[67.195.204.72]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
May 30 14:42:01 nodename postfix/smtp[28596]: C54274005F: host mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[67.195.204.72] said: 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 129.146.95.190 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN3434.html (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
May 30 14:42:01 nodename postfix/smtp[28596]: C54274005F: lost connection with mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[67.195.204.72] while sending RCPT TO
May 30 14:42:01 nodename postfix/smtp[28596]: Untrusted TLS connection established to mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[67.195.228.110]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
May 30 14:42:01 nodename postfix/smtp[28596]: C54274005F: to=<user1@yahoo.com>, relay=mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[67.195.228.110]:25, delay=0.93, delays=0.01/0/0.87/0.04, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (host mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[67.195.228.110] said: 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from [IP address] temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN3434.html (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

---

postconf -d:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
message_size_limit = 10485760
mydestination = $myhostname, example.com, mail.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = /etc/mailname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtputf8_enable = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

I have a few additional questions:
1) I understand the deferred log, but why is it still being deferred if my SPF/DKIM/DMARC have been valid for 2 weeks now?
2) What does it mean and why is there an "Untrusted TLS connection" for both Gmail and Yahoo?
3) What does it mean and why is the Network is unreachable yet the email is still delivered to Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

```
  Messages from [IP address] temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1
```

Is your answer. Your server is sending messages, but remote systems are refusing them.  You may want to check your IP against RBL blacklists and also your mail queueu to ascertain why the block is in place.

Comment: Or you jsut try again. This smells like greylisting, shutting of primitive email spammers. Reject temporarily, whitelist 10 minutes later for some hours. Most spammer systems will not try to resend, all normal email servers will.

Comment: @tomtom its not greylisting - the messages from multiple servers talk of user complaints. When grey listing is used the error typically advises this.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Apparently I am blocked on ivmSIP. I have put in a request to have myself removed from the blacklist. Is this list permanent if they do not reply? 
Also, what does it mean in the logs when it says "Untrusted TLS connection" for both Gmail and Yahoo?